# Real-world problems with naive shuffling

Tags: algorithm, probability, shuffle

I'm writing a number of articles meant to teach beginning programming concepts through the use of poker-related topics. Currently, I'm working on the subject of shuffling.

As [Jeff Atwood points out on CodingHorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html), one simple shuffling method (iterating through an array and swapping each card with a random card elsewhere in the array) creates an uneven distribution of permutations. In an actual application, I would just use the [Knuth Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) for more uniform randomness. But, I don't want to bog down an explanation of programming concepts with the much less coder-friendly algorithm.

This leads to the question: Just how much of an advantage would a black-hat have if they knew you were using a naive shuffle of a 52-card deck? It seems like it would be infinitesimally small.

Comment: The naive algorithm produces a distribution which is significantly non-uniform - the disparity is nowhere near infinitessimal. See this answer on cstheory.SE. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/39313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not like you're writing a poker program that will be used for an actual online gambling site. An ability for someone to cheat at the program isn't a big deal when you're teaching people how to program.

Leave a note saying that this is a poor model of the real world (with a reference to it as a possible security flaw), and just keep going with the teaching.

Comment: No, but the people reading these articles may go on to.  Getting shuffling right is important, because doing it wrong has caused a break before.

Comment: I hadn't, at the time I wrote that, realized the difference is so trivial. I would agree: tell them the good shuffling algorithm. Perhaps the exact details on "why" can be "refer to this literature".

Answer (score 14):

The knuth shuffle is an insignificant change compared to the naive shuffle: Just swap with any card in the remaining (unshuffled) section of the deck instead of anywhere in the entire deck. If you think of it as repeatedly choosing the next card in order from the remaining unchosen cards, it's pretty intuitive, too.

Personally, I think teaching students a poor algorithm when the proper one is no more complicated (and easier to visualise!) is a bad approach.

Comment: I agree. In this case I think both algorithms should be shown and an explanation of why one is better than the other. In this case it is a very small change and in my opinion doesn't make it more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the advantage is quite significant.  [Check out this article](http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php)

Part of the problem is the flawed algorithm, but another part is the assumption that you can get "random" numbers from a computer.

Comment: I realize that this is an old post but the link above seems broken. I would appreciate if anyone can provide a permalink.

Answer (score 3):

A simple & fair algorithm for shuffling would be to assign a random floating-point number (e.g., between 0 and 1) to each card in the deck, then sort the deck by the assigned numbers.

This is actually a perfect example for students to realize that just because something is intuitive, the naive shuffle in our case, doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: Can someone back up what KG says (if it has merit) ? This is the method I would have chosen if I hadn't read Jeff's article, but I am a simple caveman, fire frightens me.

Comment: Assuming we don't have implementation errors around the floating points, my intuition still tells me this is wrong. I can't quite explain why, though.

It would be worth running through a quick testing, though.

Comment: Regardless of whether it would provide a random shuffle, it would be slower than the KFY solution (which is O(n) in time complexity.)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an aside, there was a [blog post over on ITtoolbox](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/codesharp/more-random-than-random-25106) about shuffling that may be of interest when it comes to simulating a shuffle.

As to your question, consider that there are 52! deck configurations that one could start with that may play a role in where things land as in Jeff's example of the 3 card deck, note that the 1 in the over-represented occurs in each slot once.  Also note that he says you'd have to have a few thousand examples before it becomes apparent where the advantage is, but with a deck you aren't likely to start again with the exact same initial deck, are you?  You'd take the dealt cards and put them on the bottom and shuffle them which isn't likely to repeat I'd think.

Answer (score -1):

Subjective.

> It seems like it would be infinitesimally small.

Agree.

Comment: The difference is not even close to infinitessimal - see this answer on cstheory.SE. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/39313