# How do I generate random numbers on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

What is the best way to generate random numbers using Objective-C on iOS?
If I use `(int)((double) rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX) + (double) 1) * 5.0)` to generate a number from 0 to 4, every time I start the program on the iPhone it generates the same numbers to start off with.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is a very similar question [here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c).  Here is one of the better solutions (no need for seeding):

```
int r = arc4random() % 5;
```

Comment: 5 if they want it from 0 to 4

Comment: It gives unbiased results for all n, rather than only power-of-2 n, see the man page

Answer (score 15):

i use

```
#define RANDOM_SEED() srandom(time(NULL))
#define RANDOM_INT(__MIN__, __MAX__) ((__MIN__) + random() % ((__MAX__+1) - (__MIN__)))
```

so you can give a min and max

Answer (score 10):

You should seed the random number generator with the current time.

```
srand(time(0));
```

Answer (score 6):

How random do you need? If you want random enough for crypto, then use SecRandomCopyBytes().

Answer (score 3):

Call `srand()` at the start of your program, it'll reseed random number generator

Answer (score 2):

Simple function for random number generation:

```
int r = arc4random() % 42;  // generate number up to 42 (limit)
```

Comment: While being redundant as an answer, I like how the number 42 is being used instead of 5 here.

Comment: As I want to generate random number up to 41  so I have given 42, so it will generate between 0 to 41 including 0 & 41, as I want to use 41.

Comment: Fair enough. However, you are strongly encouraged to read "The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy" - I believe it is a non-optional reading for programmers in general.

Comment: @Toastor: Too funny ;)