# Random number generating unique numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, random

I want to generate random numbers between 1-100 in Objective-C. Each random number should be unique and not the same as a previously generated random number.

Comment: Check out the many other questions on this topic, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Comment: use arc4random() %(100);

Comment: I came across this, and I thought I should share that you should prefer arc4random_uniform(X) to arc4random() % X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arc4random() %(100)-1` this is worked for me.

Comment: From `man arc4random`: *arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound.  arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.*

Comment: also, note that the upper bound in `u_int32_t     arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t upper_bound)` is not inclusive, i.e. `arc4random_uniform(1)` will always give you zeroes.

Answer (score 78):

Check this links

- [***Generating Random Numbers in Objective-C***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

---

- [***How do I generate random numbers on the iPhone?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510367/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-on-the-iphone)

  ```
  int r = arc4random() % 100;
  ```

---

- [***Objective-C: Get random number***](http://vormplus.be/blog/article/random-numbers-in-objective-c)

  ```
  -(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from and:(int)to {

      return (int)from + arc4random() % (to-from+1);
  }
  ```

  How to use:

  1) Implement method above into your .m file

  2) Add the following line to your .h file:

  ```
  -(int)getRandomNumberBetween:(int)from and:(int)to;
  ```

  3) Call the method like:

  ```
  int randomNumber = [self getRandomNumberBetween:9 and:99];
  //this gets you a random number between 9 and 99
  ```

---

- [***Random Numbers in Objective-C***](http://vormplus.be/blog/article/random-numbers-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 5):

Use [arc4random](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/random-thoughts-rand-vs-arc4random.html) and store the results in an NSSet which will take care of the duplicates for you.

Answer (score 4):

An other easy way is to do this is the use the     arc4random_uniform() method:

Calling     arc4random_uniform(N) return a random number from 0 to N-1. To get a number from 1 to N, you can use:

```
NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(N) + 1;
```

where N is the max number that you are looking for. In Swift, you can do it as:

```
var randomIndex:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(N) + 1
```

e.g. if you want to get a random number between 1 and 100, just call as:

```
NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(100) + 1;
```

or in swift:

```
var randomIndex:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(100)+1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code which generate unique random numbers...

```
-(void)UniqueRandom{

    int T[11];
    BOOL flag;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        int ranNo=  random()%100+1;
        flag=TRUE;
        int s=(sizeof T); 

        for(int x=0;x<s;x++){

            if(ranNo==T[x]){
                i--;
                flag= FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag) T[i]=ranNo;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)  NSLog(@"unique random %d",T[j]);
    }
}
```

Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

This method will generate array of unique random number in the interval of high and low range.

```
-(void)generateRandomUniqueNumberInRange :(int)rangeLow :(int)rangeHigh{
    NSMutableArray *unqArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int randNum = arc4random() % (rangeHigh-rangeLow+1) + rangeLow;
    int counter=0;
    while (counter<rangeHigh-rangeLow) {
        if (![unqArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]]) {
            [unqArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]];
            counter++;
        }else{
            randNum = arc4random() % (rangeHigh-rangeLow+1) + rangeLow;
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"UNIQUE ARRAY %@",unqArray);

}
```