# Random AI / Switch case?

Tags: iphone, artificial-intelligence, switch-statement

So I have a very simple game going here..., right now the AI is nearly perfect and I want it to make mistakes every now and then. The only way the player can win is if I slow the computer down to a mind numbingly easy level.

My logic is having a switch case statement like this:

```
int number = randomNumber

case 1:
computer moves the complete opposite way its supposed to
case 2:
computer moves the correct way
```

How can I have it select case 2 68% (random percentage, just an example) of the time, but still allow for some chance to make the computer fail? Is a switch case the right way to go? This way the difficulty and speed can stay high but the player can still win when the computer makes a mistake.

I'm on the iPhone. If there's a better/different way, I'm open to it.

Comment: You probably ant to have some coefficient or other way to "scale" up based on user level/difficulty level

Comment: the person who can answer this question with something other than a qausi-random method should get a nobel prize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Generating Random Numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

```
int randNumber = 1 + rand() % 100;

if( randNumber < 68 )
{
//68% path
}
else
{
//32% path
}
```

Comment: This isn't perfect, of course, as rand() % 100 does not create a perfect distribution of values due to behavior near the upper end of INT.

Comment: the first path is the 32% path.

Comment: I do believe you're mistaken.

Comment: i am. and stoned. sorry, now i realise your example is equal to mine.

Comment: Like mentioned below, there's a tiny bit of error related to using modulus, but a user wouldn't notice, and you probably wouldn't either. Don't use this method for your online gambling sites, at any rate :P.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber = GeneraRandomNumberBetweenZeroAndHundred()

if (randomNumber < 68) {
computer moves the complete opposite way its supposed to
} else {
computer moves the correct way
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many PRNGs will offer a random number in the range [0,1).  You can use an if-statement instead:

```
   n = randomFromZeroToOne()

   if n <= 0.68:
        PlaySmart()
   else: 
        PlayStupid()
```

If you're going to generate an integer from 1 to N, instead of a float, beware of [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Modulo_bias) in your results.

Comment: I would expect with such a small number as 100, modulo bias would be almost unnoticeable.  Usually it's only a factor when you get into much larger numbers.

Comment: Yes, it would likely be unnoticeable with a value this small, in an application like a casual game; however, it is an issue that many programmers do not know about, so bringing that up might be helpful to someone else who comes across this question.