# Random number in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, numbers, generator

How do you generate a random number when a button is clicked, and depending on that number, different actions take place.

I probably only need a random number from 1-10.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked{

"generate the random number"

if(number == 1){

    something happens
}

else if(number == 2){
    something else happens
}

etc

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

And please, please, if you are generating a random number from 1 to 10... use switch rather than a pile of if {} else if {} clauses:

```
switch (arc4random() % 10){
case 0:
   //blah blah
   break;
case 1:
   //blah blah
   break;
//etc etc
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use a proper algorithm for generating random numbers between 0 and *n* from a uniform distribution of random numbers between 0 and *n_max*: The one implemented in java.util.Random#nextInt(int) is pretty well thought-out: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29

Answer (score 27):

There are a few problems with rand() which there are loads of posts about and they recommend that you use `arc4random()` instead. This function is seeded automatically and has a 'better' algorithm for number generation.

```
int myNumber = arc4random() % 10
```

This would mean that `myNumber` would be between 0-9.

So in your case you want:

```
int number = (arc4random() % 2) + 1;
```

which would give you a range of 1-2.

Answer (score 4):

As obj-c is a superset of c language you can freely use [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) function

Answer (score 2):

If you need a cryptographically secure random number you may use:

```
int SecRandomCopyBytes (
   SecRandomRef rnd,
   size_t count,
   uint8_t *bytes
);
```

as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success with arc4random() - just modulus it to set a range.  For instance:

arc4random() % 100;

I would actively avoid using rand() as it does not produce truly random numbers and it needs to be seeded.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];
    NSMutableArray *valueArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int  count=0;
    while(count<5)
    {
        int rand= arc4random()%10;
        NSLog(@"%d",rand);

        NSString *str=[arr objectAtIndex:rand];
        if(![valueArray containsObject:str])
        {
        [valueArray addObject:str];
         count++;
        } 
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",valueArray);
```