# Why does rand() always return the same value?

Tags: c, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067364/generating-random-numbers-in-c)
>   [using rand to generate a random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159644/using-rand-to-generate-a-random-numbers)

I'm trying to generate random numbers but i'm constantly getting the number 41.
What might be going so wrong in such a simple snippet?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = rand();
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times on SO; searching "random numbers in C" will present numerous answers. The one I link to is exactly the same as yours even producing `41`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 41 was chosen randomly. I just tried to pick a random number and didn't get 41.

Comment: So close. 42 would be better...

Comment: @FelixKling Certainly. There is inherently a problem with this code because it is giving the OP 41, and not 42.

Comment: +1 @FelixKling - I wonder how may really know what you mean??

Comment: @Chuck: I think that's part of the fun :) But as this a site which is supposed to teach: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6tINlNluuY

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to give a different seed, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    a = rand();
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to seed the generator.

This is expected. The reason is for repeatability of results. Let's say your doing some testing using a random sequence and your tests fails after a particular amount of time or iterations. If you save the seed, you can repeat the test to duplicate/debug. Seed with the current time from epoch in milliseconds and you get randoms as you expect ( and save the seed if you think you need to repeat results ).

Comment: When i use (let's say:12) srand(12) before that the number changes but its still constant

Comment: @UmutŞenaltan: Seeding with the same value *will* create the same random sequence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: This is expected.  The reason is for repeatability of results.  Let's say your doing some testing using a random sequence and your tests fails after a particular amount of time or iterations.  If you save the seed, you can repeat the test to duplicate/debug. Seed with the current time from epoch in milliseconds and you get randoms as you expect ( and save the seed if you think you need to repeat results ).