# random(int) and randomize() in C

Tags: c, random

I want to generate pseudo-random integers in a given range without introducing the skew that results from the use of `rand()%N`.

I have read about the functions `random()` and `randomize()` that seem to substitute the `rand()` and `srand()` functions but returning directly an integer in the range given as the parameter of the `random()` function. In both cases, the functions seem to be in the `stdlib.h` library.

The problem I have is that I cannot make these functions work somehow. Here's a small test code I made to test the functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
 randomize(); 
 printf("%d\n",random(100));
 return 0;
}
```

At compilation with `gcc -o test test.c` it gives an error

`test.c: In function ‘main’:

test.c:6: error: too many arguments to function ‘random’`

As far as I know the function `random()` only takes one argument which is an integer to determine the range of the numbers given. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: It seems that those correspond to some TurboC old things. So the question is now, how to make "truly" random integers in the sense that they are not skewed? My approach is (as suggested by Vatine)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  printf("%d\n",rand()/(RAND_MAX/100));
  return 0;
}
```

which seems to yield a correct result. Is this adding some bias or the results have at least equal probability of falling into any of the numbers in the range?

Comment: Check your `stdlib.h` for what prototype it has for `random()`.

Comment: Please link to where you read about `randomize()`. It does not seem to me in my standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man random` gives me that:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>

   long int random(void);
```

So the error message is correct: there are too many arguments to function ‘random’.

I don't know the function `randomize` and the `random` function I am aware of doesn't take any argument.

But I did find this on the Internet (careful, you should not use this code, I'm just saying):

```
#ifndef __TURBOC__
#define randomize() srand48(getpid())
#define random(x) (lrand48() % x)
#endif
```

So maybe it's a turbo C old thing? I also found [this example](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-generate-random-numbers) that tends to confirm it's a Turbo C specific function.

#### How to generate a random number in C

If you want to keep using `rand` and `srand`, you can do the following:

```
int random(int N) {
    return (double)rand()/RAND_MAX * N;
}
```

But you can also look for other random generators such as the Mersenne Twister. There are plenty implementations available.

Comment: +1, @gunbl4d3 : See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdlib.h.html) and [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/srandom.html) for more info.

Comment: Okay it seems I fall for this, you are right. I'll edit my question a bit then.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 Don't change your question too much otherwise the answers would not fit.

Comment: Seems the most complete answer to the whole topic. I also found another way of generating integers in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3081486/2833912

Comment: Careful, this method still won't create a uniform distribution: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. The signature for `random` is `long int random(void);`.

You can usually get better pseudo-random ranges by dividing by `RAND_MAX/N` rather than using modulus (the PRNGs use tend to be more predictable in the lower bits than in the higher bits), but if you are concerned about this, I would suggest using a battery of statistical tests to see how much bias you actually have.