# Randomize function

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am trying to create a 1000 elements array. Each element should range between 0 and 99. 
I first tried by reproduce this didactic example that, actually, I cannot comprehend correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 1000

int myVect[DIM];
int i;
int main(){
randomize();                       /∗ Initialize randomize*/
    for (i =0; i < DIM ; i ++)
        myVect[i] = random(100);
return 0;
}
```

While compiling, I got `error`, `warning` and `note`.

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘randomize’    (1)
error: too many arguments to function ‘random’           (2)
/usr/include/stdlib.h:282:17: note: declared here        (3)
```

I found resources from two posts:

- [random(int) and randomize() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976634/randomint-and-randomize-in-c])
- [How to generate a random number from within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range)

Unfortunately, because of my inexperience, I am not capable of get the meaning of the didactic example I posted.

(1) In which library is `randomize`? I have not been able to find out.

(2) `Random` should not have a parameter. Hence, why in the example it comes with `100`, as it should determine the range of the random numbers?

(3) Does this note indicate where `random` is declared?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: This is a bad example. There is no such functions in C with the standard libraries

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh for the confirmation. Then, what is the reason of such example? What is its didactic purpose?

Comment: Probably you better ask the author of it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`randomize()` and `random()` are not Standard C library functions. You can use `srand` and `rand` instead.

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));                       
for (i =0; i < DIM ; i ++)
    myVect[i] = rand()%100;
```

For `time()` function you need to include `<time.h>` header.