# How can I generate a random number in C

Tags: c, random, stdio

I want to generate a random number/character without using any libraries but <stdio.h>. Is there any possibility to do that? I mean, by doing some weird loop or something like that, I don't care, I just want to generate random stuff with the basic library.

Comment: Yes, you can write a random generator from scratch. You don't even need the standard library to do that.

Comment: Google "pseudo random number generator algorithm"

Comment: `stdio.h` is not a library.  It is a header.  It is important to understand the difference.

Comment: There is a decent example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register

Comment: You will definitely want to `#include <stdint.h>` too to get the fixed width `typedef`s like `uint32_t` etc. Then pick a good PRNG algorithm and implement it. This has a lot of interesting stuff: http://mostlymangling.blogspot.com/

Comment: It would be cheating, but if you're allowed to use functions in `<stdio.h>`, you can open and read from `/dev/random`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067364/generating-random-numbers-in-c)

Comment: @lbarqueira no, it doesn't, because he does not want to use other functions than the ones from `<stdio.h>`

Comment: You could use the code outlined in the C standard for a minimal [pseudo-random number generator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.2p5).  It isn't clear whether you're allowed to use functions of your own, or whether the only functions other than `main()` can be those declared in the `<stdio.h>` header.  Also, it isn't clear if your program must output a random number when it is invoked, or whether there is other code in the program that will use it.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *f, e = 3;

    f = &e;

    printf("%d", f);

    return 0;
}
```

its not realy random but the best you can do with stdio.h

you have a pointer and the pointer points on a variable named 'e'. and then you print the memory adress of the pointer

Comment: [Dilbert](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25) found a random number generator like this.

Comment: Note that printing an address is not done with `%d`, too.

Comment: This is very far from the best that can be done