# How can I get a Random quote (text) from a database (CoreData) of quotes? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, random

I want to develop an app that gives a random quote every time you change the page. And I want to put like 1000 quotes in the database. How is the best way I can get a Random Quote?  arc4random?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the answer you were given on selecting a method to generate a random number - choose a random number method, and have an index for each quote in the DB so that you can query a quote directly from the random number you compute.

Also you can get counts directly from Core Data (without doing a real query) to figure out the range of random numbers you want to ask for.