# Question about creating classes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am really new to objective C, and I want to make a class that is an NSArray of NSDictionary, and then have a method that grabs a random entries.  I know how to make that but I don't understand how to make it in the class.  What I mean is I thought that you could put the code that declared (or whatever the correct terminology is) the array just sort of in the middle of the implementation file and then I would write a method under that. The only instance variable I had was the NSArray and that was in the interface file, along with the method prototype (or whatever) and these were the only things that were in the interface file.

I couldn't figure out the problem so I made a test class that was the same but with just an array of simple text strings.  I used the same logic here and I'm pretty certain it is totally backward, I don't know in which way though.

**This is the interface for the test class:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface TestClass : NSObject {
    NSArray *TestArray;
}


@end
```

**And this is the implementation file**

```
#import "TestClass.h"


@implementation TestClass{
    NSArray *TestArray;
}
TestArray = [[NSArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:@"stuff",@"things",@"example",@"stuffThings",nil];

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read [Apple's introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html). It explains the syntax and structure of the language. You must also read the [Objective-C memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) so that your programs don't leak memory and crash.

Having said that, here's probably what you're trying to create (I took the liberty of changing some of your variable names):

`TestClass.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject {
  NSArray* strings_;
}

// Method declarations would go here
// example:
- (NSString*)randomElement;

@end
```

`TestClass.m`

```
#import "TestClass.h"
#import <stdlib.h>

// Notice how the implementation does NOT redefine the instance variables.
@implementation TestClass

// All code must be in a method definition.

// init is analogous to the default constructor in other languages
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    strings_ = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"stuff", @"things", nil];
  }
  return self;
}

// dealloc is the destructor (note the call to super).
- (void)dealloc {
  [strings_ release];
  [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString*)randomElement {
  NSUInteger index = arc4random() % [strings_ count];
  return [strings_ objectAtIndex:index];
}

@end
```

For [random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c/163178#163178), it's easy to use `arc4random()` because it doesn't require setting the seed value.