# loading items from index

Tags: iphone

i am trying to get a random number of items from an an array of dictionaries that contains 2 items. one item is at index 1 and the other is at index 0. i want to randomly alternate between the two or have the able to be viewed in a random order each item. (i know i have just 2 items ill increase the amount)
this is the code im trying to get to randomize with the index 0 and index 1 files.

```
   - (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   NSDictionary *dict = [data_ objectAtIndex:0];
   UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"fullsize"];
   return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[some question for random function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)
according to it, you can do

```
int index = arc4random() % 2;
```

**edit**
here is a [category on NSMuteableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray/56656#56656) to shuffle its objetcs

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUinteger index = arc4random() %([data_ count] +1);
```