# A UITabBarController that has a default startup view

Tags: iphone, view, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController`, and one of the views I would like to display a startup message describing itself with directions (This is a view for selecting random sports teams).  There would be a separate button on the navigation bar, which when pressed would populate the `UIView` with a view about a random sports team.  Press that button again, and a different team is displayed.  So, let's say I go to a different item that's listed on the `UITabBar`, and later return to this random view.  I want the view to be the last sports team displayed, **not** the startup directions page.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to implement this case?

Comment: Can you try make it simple what exactly you want, it's not clear or rather confusing. at least for me.;,, :(

Comment: I've edited this.  Does it sound any clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement some algorithm to random the data to load in that view after u leave that view through viewDidDisappear method

EDIT: Scratch that, use UITabBarDelegate method. From what i understand you are trying to load a view differently every time the user pressed it.

> -(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item

This method is called when your tab bar item is pressed, you could check whether the tab bar item is the tab bar item you wanted then do some random number generation in that method and load the view probably from an NSArray containing the team objects using the random number. For more information, read up:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html
and [Generating random numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

Comment: Could you possibly explain in detail?