# How to write raw bytes to an NSMutableData object?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ok, I'm a little stumped here, as I've never really dealt with anything this low level. Say I want to add the following bytes to an `NSMutableData` object:

```
0x01, 0xF, 0x64, 0x0, 0x6A
```

How do I even go about doing this? I imagine it's something to do with the `appendBytes:length:` method, but I honestly don't know how to transform what I have above into an NSMutableData.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338975/convert-hex-data-string-to-nsdata-in-objective-c-cocoa and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917968/best-way-to-generate-nsdata-object-with-random-bytes-of-a-specific-length can help you...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
char bytesToAppend[5] = {0x01, 0xf0, 0x64, 0x0, 0x6a};
[data appendBytes:bytesToAppend length:sizeof(bytesToAppend)];
```