# Using SecRandomCopyBytes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift5

I want to generate random bytes using `SecRandomCopyBytes` in Swift 3.0. Here is how I did it in Swift 2.2

```
private static func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {
    let data = NSMutableData(length: Int(32))

    let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 32, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(data!.mutableBytes))
    if result == errSecSuccess {
        return data!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    } else {
        print("Problem generating random bytes")
        return nil
    }
}
```

In Swift 3, I tried to do it like this, since I know the concept of unsafemutablebytes is different now, but it doesn't allow me to return. If I comment out the return part, it still says `Generic Parameter ResultType could not be inferred`

```
fileprivate static func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {
    var keyData = Data(count: 32)
    _ = keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {mutableBytes in
        let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, keyData.count, mutableBytes)
        if result == errSecSuccess {
            return keyData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        } else {
            print("Problem generating random bytes")
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You were close, but `return` inside the closure returns
from the closure, not from the outer function.
Therefore only `SecRandomCopyBytes()` should be called in the
closure, and the result passed back.

```
func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {

    var keyData = Data(count: 32)
    let result = keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        (mutableBytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> Int32 in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 32, mutableBytes)
    }
    if result == errSecSuccess {
        return keyData.base64EncodedString()
    } else {
        print("Problem generating random bytes")
        return nil
    }
}
```

For a  "single-expression closure" the closure type can inferred
automatically, so this can be shortened to

```
func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {

    var keyData = Data(count: 32)
    let result = keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 32, $0)
    }
    if result == errSecSuccess {
        return keyData.base64EncodedString()
    } else {
        print("Problem generating random bytes")
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Swift 5 update:**

```
func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {

    var keyData = Data(count: 32)
    let result = keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 32, $0.baseAddress!)
    }
    if result == errSecSuccess {
        return keyData.base64EncodedString()
    } else {
        print("Problem generating random bytes")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeOverRide: Thanks for fixing the "overlapping access" issue. I have simplified a bit, copying the data is not necessary. It suffices not to use `keyData.count` inside the closure.

Comment: yea, just found that that is not needed.

Comment: This is no longer valid in Swift 5 as now `withUnsafeMutableBytes` exposes a `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer` instead of a `UnsafeMutablePointer`.

Comment: @MartinR, Can we generate a random number in a range like `arc4random_uniform(<num>)` with `SecRandomCopyBytes` ?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal: Not out of the box, but it is not too difficult to implement (similarly as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550169/1187415). But note that starting with Swift 4.2, the Swift standard library provides a random number generator which –  according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/systemrandomnumbergenerator – is cryptographically secure.

Comment: is it safe to force unwrap the base address here ?

Comment: @VinayHosamane Yes. If the data is not empty then the base address is not nil.

Comment: @MartinR - quick question, in the Swift 5 version, you use $0.baseAddress to refer to specify a pointer to the start of the memory location for the keyData variable (I think)? --- how does this syntax work, I thought $0 was a shortcut to the first "parameter" of the closure, this doesn't make sense to me here, as the closure has no params.

Comment: @Woodstock: The closure of [`withUnsafeMutableBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2633739-withunsafemutablebytes) has one parameter of type `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer` and `$0` is the shortcut syntax for that parameter. The “verbose” version would be `keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bufPtr in
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 32, bufPtr.baseAddress! )`

Comment: @MartinR - many thanks sir. OK that makes sense, but how then does `keyData` end up filled with the random bytes, instead it should be `bufPtr` with only closure level scope, no? or does `bufPtr` escape the closure? I mean we return `keyData` not `bufPtr` or `$0`.

Comment: @Woodstock: The closure is called with bufPtr set to the address (and length) of the element storage of keyData. So SecRandomCopyBytes is called with a pointer to that element storage, and fills the bytes of keyData.

Answer (score 13):

This is the simplest and "Swiftiest" way to implement your function using Swift 5:

```
func generateRandomBytes() -> String? {
    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 32)
    let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, bytes.count, &bytes)

    guard result == errSecSuccess else {
        print("Problem generating random bytes")
        return nil
    }

    return Data(bytes).base64EncodedString()
}
```

Generally it is best practice in Swift to use guard statements as opposed to if/else statements when the control flow of a function depends on the success or failure of an expression or the presence of a non-nil value.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1399291-secrandomcopybytes) it looks similar to this:

```
public func randomData(ofLength length: Int) throws -> Data {
    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
    let status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, &bytes)
    if status == errSecSuccess {
        return Data(bytes: bytes)
    }
    // throw an error
}
```

or as an additional initializer:

```
public extension Data {
    public init(randomOfLength length: Int) throws {
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
        let status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, length, &bytes)
        if status == errSecSuccess {
            self.init(bytes: bytes)
        } else {
            // throw an error
        }
    }
}
```