# How to use 'Data.withUnsafeMutableBytes' in swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

I updated a project to Swift 5, it generates a key for encryption somewhere with the following piece of code:

```
let result = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
}
```

With the update to Swift 5 I get the following warning:

```
'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead
```

But I have no idea how to implement what it wants from me, I find the suggestion vague at best and anything I try either doesn't compile or gives the same warning.

Here is the full function:

```
static func generateEncryptionKey() -> Data {
    /// Generate a random encryption key
    var key = Data(count: 64)

    let result = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { bytes in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, bytes)
    }
    assert(result == 0, "Failed to get random bytes")

    let keyHexString = (key as NSData).hexStringRepresentation()
    debugPrint("Newly generated encryption key - \(keyHexString)")

    return key
}
```

I've tried various ways of writing `withUnsafeMutableBytes` but to no avail. What would be a suitable alternative for above code in Swift 5?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820681/1187415, which has been updated for Swift 5.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot, that works. I don't know if you want to post an answer I can accept? Else I'll just mark this Q as duplicate.