# Problem randomizing number in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random, floating-point, numbers

I am trying to generate a random number between 0 and the size of my array:

```
    float randomNum = (rand() / RAND_MAX) * [items count];
    NSLog(@"%f",randomNum);
    NSLog(@"%d",[items count]);
```

randomNum is always 0.0000000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int randomNum = arc4random() % ([items count] +1);
```

note that `randomNum` won't do as an array reference.  To do that, you want:

```
int randomRef = arc4random() % [items count];
id myRandomObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:randomRef];
```

`arc4random()` returns an `u_int32_t` (int) which makes it easily transferrable to stuff like dice, arrays, and other real-world problems unlike `rand()`

Answer (score 6):

> randomNum is always 0.0000000

That's because you're doing integer division instead of floating-point division; `(rand() / RAND_MAX)` will almost always be 0. (Exercise to the reader: when is it not 0?)

Here's one way to fix that:

```
float randomNum = ((float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX) * [items count];
```

You should also be using [arc4random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c) instead.

Comment: I still get 0 using that snippet.

Comment: @SheehanAlam Do yourself a favour and switch to `arc4random` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you want it between 0 and your array size it should be:

```
randomNum = random() % [items count];  // between 0 and arraySize-1
```

If you want your array size included:

```
randomNum = random() % ([items count]+1);  // between 0 and arraySize
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `rand() * [items count];`

IIRC, `rand()` returns values between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

people say that arc4random() is the best rnd method...

you can use it this way to get a number in a range:

```
int fromNumber = 0;
int toNumber = 50;
float randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;
NSLog(@"random number is:  %f",randomNumber); // you'll get from 0 to 49
```

...

```
int fromNumber = 12;
int toNumber = 101;
float randomNumber = (arc4random()%(toNumber-fromNumber))+fromNumber;
NSLog(@"random number is:  %f",randomNumber); // you'll get from 12 to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using rand() you must set a seed, you do so by calling the srand function and passing a seed.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) for the srand documentation and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) for rand.