# Objective C - Create Multiple TextFields for the User, then randomly select one and output the Entered Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textbox, user-input, edit

Basically what I am trying to do is:

1) The user sets the number of choices he wants e.g. 3 choices which are "A", "B", "C"
      **[Done this]**

2) The next view is loaded and the right amount of boxes are created, 3 in this case. The boxes need to be blank at first and then the user enters their choices into the boxes. 
e.g. "A", "B", "C"

Note: I tried create multiple text boxes automatically, but I found that after about 6 boxes the screen wouldn't scroll and therefore looked very tacky

3)At a click of a button, one of the textboxes is selected randomly. The inputed data from this randomly selected box is then displayed in NSLog or Label or file, which i will then use in another view.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Hey, you could make a scrollView out of the 2th view. That way, you can still automatically create textfields, and the screen will scroll. Check out [this](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/12/how-to-use-uiscrollview-in-your-iphone-app/) link for more information on how to create a scrollview. Perhaps you can make the scrollview's size dynamically (depending on how much textfields you have).

About selecting a random textfield, use `arc4random()` More about that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c).