# Randomly pick between 2 defined ints

Tags: objective-c

Is there a method in objective-c that allows you to pseudorandomly decide between two ints? Or is there a quick way to implement this?

Comment: For a detailed discussion on Random numbers in objective-c (including why you shouldn't use rand!) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
int number = arc4random() % 2;
if(number==0){
  //pick one number
}else{
  //pick other number
}
```

Comment: A slight better looking is to use ternary operator. +1 though.

Comment: That is a uselessly heavy calculation. Why arc4? No simple random that returns float in between 0 and 0,(9) in ObjC?

Answer (score 2):

```
randomSelection = arc4random() % 2 ? choice1 : choice2;
```

Answer (score 0):

in C++ that would be `result = rand() < 0.5 ? int1 : int2`
why can't you build the same command in ObjC?

Comment: This will almost always return int2 unless rand() returns 0.

Comment: Why? `rand()` returns float. May be it's Linux-specific? Anyway, I assume it is easy enough to figure out what I meant with this code.

Comment: In which version of C++ or GCC rand() returns float?