# How to choose a random case in a switch statement

Tags: objective-c

I want to output several questions, but in a random order. How can I ask all questions randomly without repeating one?

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int question=rand()%4;
    switch(question)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"What is your name");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Who are you");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"What is your name");
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"How do you do");
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"Are you?");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the `for` loop from the `switch`?

Comment: Just a tip: putting "Random question" as the question title is probably not a good idea because it sounds like you're just asking some random question. Something like "how to choose a random case in a switch statement" might have been better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep the questions in an array.  Shuffle the array at the start of questioning.  Now pull one question from the list per iteration, ask it, get the answer, and continue until you run out of questions.

Comment: Upon further reading, I think this is a better answer - the OP's question is pretty vague, but this answer might be the one he's looking for.

Comment: @Josh@Joe@Carl Norum    Thank yu for your attention to me

Answer (score 4):

`rand(3)` is pretty famous for having poor implementations that have pretty short cycles for  the lower bits.  Try using different bits, or use `random(3)` instead.  In fact, the [`rand(3)` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/rand.3.html) on OS X says:

> These interfaces are obsoleted by [**`random(3)`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/random.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/random).

Also - `% 4` can never be larger than 3, so your `case 4` will never execute in this program.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use [`arc4random()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c) for a better algorithm with out the need to seed. Otherwise call [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) to seed your call to [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/).

Comment: Thanks for this useful information, but is the any method to avoid repeats completely?

Comment: Nathan - I think @Marvo's answer hit what you're looking for.

Comment: @Carl Norum I agree with you as that is probably the expected results.