# What is a good Random function to use that will be different every time it starts

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using rand() function, but it always uses the same random sequence.  Is there a random function that seeds with the clock value?  And how would I do this?

Comment: arc4random(). Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are meant to seed `rand()` and `random()` (slightly bigger space) yourself, with their respective seed functions, before using them. You can use the time, or whatever other value you desire:

```
srand(time(0));
srandom(time(0));
```

Here we get the system time; obviously passing a constant will produce the same sequence every run.

You can also use [`arc4random()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) which generates very high-quality random bits and seeds itself using /dev/random.

Comment: Use `arc4random()`, there really is little reason not to and there ae no seeding issues.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` requires you to specify the seed. The best way to specify a seed is to use the current time.

```
// specify the seed
srand(time(NULL));
```

Or you can use [arc4random](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/arc4random/).

Comment: If you have any interest in security do not seed with the clock, that is just to easy to crack.