# iOS Random Number Generator to a new view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I need some help with an app. I need to make a random number generator for integers between zero and fifteen, which will then, depending on which number is created, push to a view with the corresponding number. 
This is how I want it to work

Push a button --> random number generator gives a number between 0 and 15 --> view pushes to another view that has been assigned the number that the random number generator gave.

Can anybody help me with the code?
Thanks

Comment: which code are you talking about ?

Comment: Here is a link regarding random number generation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`arc4random()` is the standard Objective-C random number generator function. It'll give you a number between zero and... well, more than fifteen! You can generate a number between 0 and 15 (so, 0, 1, 2, ... 15) with the following code:

```
NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 16;
```

Then you can do a switch or a series of `if`/`else` statements to push a different view controller:

```
UIViewController *viewController = nil;
switch (randomNumber)
{
    case 0:
        viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    break;
    // etc ...
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Or rather, upon rereading the question, it would look like the following:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" 
viewController.number = randomNumber;
```

And you'd have an `NSInteger` property on the MyViewController subclass.

Comment: The function arc4random_uniform() is preferred since it doesn't suffer from modulo bias.

Comment: Does this function generate psuedo random number? what seed does it use?

Comment: @CharlesChow quoting the man page, `"The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by the arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8 bit S-Boxes.  The
     S-Boxes can be in about (2**1700) states.  The arc4random() function returns pseudo-random numbers in the range of 0 to
     (2**32)-1, and therefore has twice the range of rand(3) and random(3)."`

Answer (score 19):

You can use `arc4random_uniform`

```
NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(16);
```

Comment: In 64 bit mode, arc4random_uniform returns a 32-bit int and NSUInteger is a 64-bit int, right?

Comment: u_int32_t
  arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t /*upper_bound*/) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);

It looks like it's always an unsigned int on 32 bits.

Answer (score 12):

According to Apple, the best way is to use arc4random_uniform and pass the upper bound:

```
arc4random_uniform(16)
```

From the docs:

> **arc4random_uniform()** will return a uniformly distributed random number
>   less than upper_bound. **arc4random_uniform()** is recommended over
>   constructions like ``arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo
>   bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html

Answer (score 9):

```
    int randomIndex = arc4random() % 14 + 1 ; // gives no .between 1 to 15 ..

    switch (randomIndex)
{
    case 0 :
    push view 1 ;
    break;

    case 1:
    ...

}
```

Comment: or `arc4random() % 16` to match the correct range, also `arc4random() % 14 + 1` gives `[1,14]`.

Comment: why the -1? other then the % 14 + 1; I don't see anything wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2, we don't have to call some "arc4random_uniform" function for creating random numbers, now we can just call a function "random(in:RANGE)".

```
//Create Random numbers Swift 4.2

//Int
let randomInt = Int.random(in: 1...10)

//Double
let radomDouble = Double.random(in: 1...10)

//Float
let randomFloat = Double.random(in: 1...10)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the C function `rand()` for this:

This generates an integer between 1 and 30. Alternatively you can use the `arc4random` function like this:

```
int i = arc4random() % 30;
NSLog(@"Random Number: %i", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension CGFloat {
   static func random() -> CGFloat {
       return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
   }
}
```