# Refactoring Objective C... I know this is sloppy, how can I make it pretty?

Tags: ios, objective-c, refactoring

I just wrote this:

```
- (IBAction)weatherButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    BOOL cloudy = NO;
    int rando = arc4random()%101;

    if (rando <= 50) {
        cloudy = YES;}
    else {
        cloudy = NO;
    }

    if (cloudy) {
        self.weatherLabel.text = @"no, it's cloudy.";
    } else {
        self.weatherLabel.text = @"yes, it's clear!";
    }

    NSLog(@"rando: %d", rando);
}
```

I know it's super sloppy. Also, I couldn't figure out how to get my random number to actually appear in my weatherLabel text next to the result of cloudy or clear. It seems like there should be a way to set the Boolean to just be random without the rando variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573395/ios-random-number-generator-to-a-new-view

Comment: Remember, "shorter" isn't the goal of refactoring.

Comment: @JonReid true, but the short answer was also cool. Which one would you have chosen and why?

Comment: The short answer _is_ cool. I'd expand it by extracting an explaining variable for `arc4random()%2`. But going further for unit testing, I'd want a way to inject the randomizer, so that tests can inject predetermined values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method choose random object from an array.

```
- (IBAction)weatherButtonPressed:(id)sender {
  self.weatherLabel.text = @[@"no, it's cloudy.",@"yes, it's clear!"][arc4random()%2];
}
```

Comment: works! that's clever. So it picks a random value from the array just because? or is the random number telling it which piece of the array to grab?

Comment: @[@"no, it's cloudy.",@"yes, it's clear!"] is an array. arc4random()%2 generate a random integer between 0 and 1. @[][index] syntax means it chooses an object from the array at index.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it .. I could also do a third state for the weather and increase the random number, yes?

Comment: - (IBAction)weatherButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.weatherLabel.text = @[@"no, it's cloudy.",@"yes, it's clear!",@"hard to tell, partly cloudy."][arc4random()%3];
    ;
    }

Comment: @pixelfairy That's pretty good. When the array goes larger, it's better to code like this:  

    `NSArray *array = @[XX, XX, XX, XX];  
    self.weatherLabel.text = array[arc4random()%array.count];`

Comment: sweet! I will try it in that format. I feel so smart now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Does it look better?

```
- (IBAction)weatherButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    BOOL cloudy = arc4random()%2 == 0 ;
    if (cloudy) {
        self.weatherLabel.text = @"no, it's cloudy.";
    } else {
        self.weatherLabel.text = @"yes, it's clear!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is definitely nice and short.

Answer (score 0):

My take on a refactoring:

```
- (IBAction)weatherButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *weatherText;

    if ([self isCloudy]) {
        weatherText = @"no, it's cloudy.";
    }
    else {
        weatherText = @"yes, it's clear!";
    }

    self.weatherLabel.text = weatherText;
}

- (BOOL)isCloudy {
    return arc4random_uniform(1) == 0;
}
```

Or a more direct refactoring of `isCloudy`:

```
- (BOOL)isCloudy {
    BOOL cloudy = NO;

    int rando = arc4random_uniform(101);
    NSLog(@"rando: %d", rando);

    if (rando <= 50) {
        cloudy = YES;
    }

    return cloudy;
}
```