# How to generate random number

Tags: objective-c

I am working on calculator application. For me all operations are cleared except "rand". Could any one tell me how to generate random number of some number by selecting rand.

For example 
initially i select one(1) then rand... if so it has to be displayed random number of one(1).

Comment: Check this link. Its already there.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective-C you should use (for between 0 and 1)

```
int r = arc4random() % 10;

float r2 = r/10
```

Imagine that you want a number between 0 and 50 with decimals, then you should do:

```
int r = arc4random()%50*100;
float r2 = r/100;
```

You will get something like 40.123

Comment: Its impossible, I just tried this: int r = arc4random() % 3; and its giving mew numbers like 2, 1, etc..

Comment: Yeah its giving random numbers but i want that random number in between  0 to 1 only . Thanking you

Comment: whatever number i may give it has to display random number in between 0 and one only

Comment: I dont understand, my code is giving you a random number between 0 and 1!

Comment: Sorry for keep on disturbing u and depending up on u ... could u check my following code if ([str isEqualToString:@"rand"]) 
    {
       int x = [currentVal intValue];
        double randomNumber = arc4random()%x;
        NSLog(@"%f",randomNumber);
    }

Comment: What I understand is that you want a random number between 0 and X With decimals?

Comment: yeah ... BUt not knowing how to do

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.. But it has to generate as 0.4523204802 or 0.24992334234 and so on

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger num = (arc4random() % maxnumber) + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Check the synopsis...

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include

```
 u_int32_t
 arc4random(void);

 void
 arc4random_stir(void);

 void
 arc4random_addrandom(unsigned char *dat, int datlen);
```

DESCRIPTION
     The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by the arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8
     bit S-Boxes.  The S-Boxes can be in about (2**1700) states.  The arc4random() function returns pseudo-
     random numbers in the range of 0 to (2**32)-1, and therefore has twice the range of rand(3) and
     random(3).

```
 The arc4random_stir() function reads data from /dev/urandom and uses it to permute the S-Boxes via
 arc4random_addrandom().

 There is no need to call arc4random_stir() before using arc4random(), since arc4random() automatically
 initializes itself.
```

EXAMPLES
     The following produces a drop-in replacement for the traditional rand() and random() functions using
     arc4random():

```
       #define foo4random() (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1))
```