# How do I generate a random number in C4? [C4Framework]

Tags: ios, c4

How do I generate a random number using the C4 Alpha Api?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating Random Numbers in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL greg is asking about a framework called C4, which has a built in method for doing this... So, his question is valid. No need for the attitude.

Comment: @Randolpho Greg is referring to a framework called C4. There is a method for generating random numbers, but it isn't documented yet, so this isn't really a duplicate question.

Comment: @C4-Travis Fair enough. Looks like C4 is getting a fair number of questions on Stack Overflow, so I went ahead and added a C4 tag.

Comment: wicked! I don't have enough rep yet to do that... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C4 you can use the C4Math class, which has a class-level method called randomInt...

`[C4Math randomInt:255];` will give you a random number between 0 and 255.

There is also a `randomIntBetweenA:andB:` method as well...

`[C4Math randomIntBetweenA:100 andB:200]` will give you a randomInt between 100 and 200...

Under the hood, these methods look like this:

```
+(NSInteger)randomInt:(NSInteger)value {
    srandomdev();
    return ((NSInteger)random())%value;
}

+(NSInteger)randomIntBetweenA:(NSInteger)a andB:(NSInteger)b{
    NSInteger returnVal;
    if (a == b) {
        returnVal = a;
    }
    else {
        NSInteger max = a > b ? a : b;
        NSInteger min = a < b ? a : b;
        NSAssert(max-min > 0, @"Your expression returned true for max-min <= 0 for some reason");
        srandomdev();
        returnVal = (((NSInteger)random())%(max-min) + min);
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```