# OS requirements for arc4random_uniform()

Tags: ios, c, macos, bsd, arc4random

How do I find out the minimum OS requirements for using `arc4random_uniform()`? Is it defined in BSD? If so, from what version? Does it run on any Mac OS X version? How about iOS versions? Is there any official place I can find these things out?

Comment: By reading the appropriate C library on the appropriate platform.. I don't know of a "comparison compatibility matrix", though. Sometimes the documentation will say "since" or "conforms to".

Comment: @pst, you mean I should check all possible platforms, with all possible versions, to see if I can find a man page for it?

Comment: At least the platform(s) of immediate interest, yes.

Comment: @pst, unfortunately I don't have access to all possible iOS versions and all possible BSD versions with all possible variations or all possible MacOS X versions to test on... If this is the only way, then I suppose I'll just have to refrain from using the function...

Comment: It's been in BSD [since at least 1997](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) (similar non-OSX sources agree) ... But [this says only since iOS 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c) ..

Comment: @pst, indeed... That's why I was asking. `arc4random()` does seem to be defined by BSD, but `arc4random_uniform()` seems to be a recent addition, and it doesn't even have a separate man page.

Comment: Recent to iOS, yes. To BSD/OSX ... not so recent. It seems like there should be a libc reference specific to iOS?

Comment: @pst, oh, I thought iOS has always been a full BSD implementation. This makes me wonder...

Comment: My mistake: looks like I was reading the dates wrong... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [`stdlib.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.13/include/stdlib.h) where it is defined, it says:

```
u_int32_t arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t /*upper_bound*/) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
```

So it is available from Lion on for desktops and iOS 4.3 on the iPhone.

Comment: Ooh, very clever. *shakes fist at the documentation*. +1 here.

Comment: @qegal I was wrong :( ARC4 has been part of BSB since 1997. [arc4random_uniform has only recently "been exposed"](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libbsd/2011-June/000038.html). I made the incorrect assumption that the manual dates were updated on last-change. So, while it's [possibly] *been* there, it has been *exposed* recently.

Comment: I was using this in a multiplatform environment, and ran into an issue now where it just does not work/exist for Android. Nothing to do?

Comment: @Jonny Only thing to do is to use a different function :|