# displaying a random word and username

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Why is this not working?

```
NSString *username = [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] alias];

random(); { 
    int text = rand() % 4;
    switch (text) {
        case 0: mainTextController.text = username,@"LEOONS"; break;
        case 1: mainTextController.text = username,@"AAIING"; break;
        case 2: mainTextController.text = username,@"AALBES"; break;
        case 3: mainTextController.text = username,@"AALDĲK"; break;


        default:
        break;        }
}
```

tried with different setups but just won't work

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is `mainTextController.text = username,@"LEOONS";`. Comma does not concatenate Objective-C string objects (nor C strings, for the record). What you mean is:

```
mainTextController.text = [username stringByAppendingString:@"LEOONS"];
```

(Further info on how the comma works in C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator. I believe in this case, you're setting `text` to `username` and then evaluating, but not using the result of, `@"LEOONS"`.)

Comment: Yes I know because it was only showing the username so I tried with [] because within those I mostly use comma's but ill check that out thanks for the answer you made my day :D :) !

Comment: Be sure to check out fabian789's answer as well; as he points out, your entire method could be improved.

Answer (score 3):

As andyvn22 said, you need to use `-stringByAppendingString:` to join two strings. I would like to add that your problem could be solved much nicer like this:

```
NSString *username = [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] alias];
NSArray *randomAddons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         @"LEOONS",
                         @"AAIING",
                         @"AALBES"
                         /* Add as many as you want here.... */, nil];
int randomIndex = arc4random() % [randomAddons count];
mainTextController.text = [username stringByAppendingString:[randomAddons objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
```

(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c) for information about `arc4random()`)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanted, to be more random and more future proof :-)

```
NSString *username = [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] alias];
int text = arc4random_uniform(4); //Don't do this: rand() % val or arc4random() % val
switch (text) {
    case 0: mainTextController.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",username,@"LEOONS"]; break;
    case 1: mainTextController.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",username,@"AAIING"]; break;
    case 2: mainTextController.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",username,@"AALBES"]; break;
    case 3: mainTextController.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",username,@"AALDĲK"]; break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

but better would be:

```
NSMutableArray* names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[names addObject:@"LEOONS"];
[names addObject:@"AAIING"];
[names addObject:@"AALBES"];
[names addObject:@"AALDĲK"];

NSString *username = [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] alias];
int text = arc4random_uniform([names count]); //again use arc4random_uniform
mainTextController.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",username,[names objectAtIndex:text]];
```