# Generating random date of current month

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to get a random date of the current month.

Is there any easy way to get the random date of the month?

Comment: use random function for number of days in current month

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; 
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:today];
NSRange days = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                       inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit 
                      forDate:today];
```

To generate random number, use

```
int r = arc4random() % days.length;
```

and then create a date

```
[dateComponents setDay:r];
NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was about to suggest the edit you made (re: components and creating the actual date...) +1!

Comment: Note that for a better distribution random_uniform() should be used. See this comments for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7082580/751268

Comment: Ok this is good one. But will you please tell me in last line of answer the meaning of `c` in `[c dateFromComponents:dateComponents];`

Comment: That is calendar, that was my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Swift version:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
guard
    let days = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date),
    let randomDay = days.randomElement()
else {
        return nil
}
dateComponents.setValue(randomDay, for: .day)
return calendar.date(from: dateComponents)
```