# Random with selected number in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I have numbers in integer that is 0, 17, 23, 44, 57, 60, 66, 83, 89, 91, 100, but i want to random 6 number from that number, how to do that? I can show only for one random number from 0-100 but i dont know how to show 6 number from selected number. Please teach.

Comment: those integer value inserted into array or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to pick six numbers without repetitions from the array, shuffle the array using [Knuth-Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and take the first six numbers:

```
int data[] = {0, 17, 23, 44, 57, 60, 66, 83, 89, 91, 100};
// Knuth-Fisher-Yates
for (int i = 10 ; i > 0 ; i--) {
    int n = rand() % (i+1);
    int tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[n];
    data[n] = tmp;
}
```

The first six elements of the `data` array contain a random selection from the original 11-element array.

Comment: +1 : indeed he needs a shuffle behavior not a random one in this particular case !

Answer (score 1):

Put the numbers in an array. Use a random number generator to get a random number between 0 and 1 less than the length of the array, and then get the number at that index.

That's just one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

For fetching the random number into array for that following code may be useful to you

```
[array objectAtIndex: (random() % [array count])]
```

Here is the example

```
NSUInteger firstObject = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<[myNSMutableArray count];i++) {
    NSUInteger randomIndex = random() % [myNSMutableArray count];
    [myNSMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:firstObject withObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    firstObject +=1;

}
```

Comment: Your implementation contains a very common [implementation error of picking a random element from the entire range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors). The selection is biased, as explained in the wiki article.

Comment: Thanks for informing me.+1 for it

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Generating random numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

There are lots of ways to do this. This particular method has a very good response. To get 6 random numbers simply run the function 6 times.