# Randomly access keys from dictionary

Tags: objective-c

I have a dictionary of objects that I would like to access in a random order.
It doesn't have to be properly random but just have a good amount of variation.

The dictionary looks something like this like this:

```
'customer0' : '<Customer Object>'
'customer1' : 'inactive'
'customer2' : 'inactive'
'customer3' : 'inactive'
'customer4' : '<Customer Object>'
```

The key corresponds to a UI element that will be used to represent a customer in a game and basically I want them to not appear in the same order everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About random numbers [read more here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c). So if you have string keys, you can use smth like this:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"customer%d", arc4random()%5];
<customer object> *customObj = [yourDictionary objectForKey:key];
```

Comment: Cheers. I combined this with a while loop to randomly select the inactive customers.

Answer (score 2):

In pseudocode:

1. Create a copy of the structure - you can get the keys into an array
2. Pick a random integer n from 0 to the size of the copy -1
3. Extract (as in retrieve and delete) the element at position n
4. Repeat from 2) until size == 0

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but something along these lines should achieve what you're aiming for:

```
//create dictionary
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionary];

//gather set of keys from array of keys
NSSet *keys = [NSSet setWithArray:[dictionary allKeys]];

//gather random key
NSString *key = [keys anyObject];

//gather dictionary value with key
NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
```

By creating an `NSSet` from the `NSArray` of dictionary keys, you can use `anyObject` to gather an random key from the array.

There are surely other ways to achieve this but this is the most concise approach I can think of.

Comment: Granted, `NSSet` is unordered, but `anyObject` won't return a random object from the set!

Comment: Agreed. But this approach seemed cleaner than using arc4random. The NSSet documentation states: `The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience—the selection is not guaranteed to be random.`