# random CGPointMake of uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I change this number "63" in my code?

```
-(void)up
{


    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self randomFloatBetween:1.0 and:0.3] animations:^{
        m1.center = CGPointMake(63, 210);
    }];


   [self performSelector:@selector(down) withObject:nil afterDelay:[self randomFloatBetween:1.0 and:0.5]];
 }
```

Number 63 from my CGPointMake should be random. So For number 63 I need to be random these numbers: 160 & 257.

My "m1" image, appear at CGPointMake(63, 210), BUT I want to make Point 63 random, to change from 63 to 160 or 257. RANDOM. Thnaks a lot.

Comment: Can you explain, please. I'm beginner. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/160890/900873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)up
{
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:63],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:160],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:257], nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self randomFloatBetween:1.0 and:0.3] animations:^{
        m1.center = CGPointMake([[myArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [myArray count]] floatValue], 210);
    }];
    [self performSelector:@selector(down) withObject:nil afterDelay:[self randomFloatBetween:1.0 and:0.5]];
}
```

Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the desired numbers to an NSArray, and select the number with `[yourArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random()%yourArray.count)];`

Comment: not working. Point 63 is float. Can you write a simple code, please.

Comment: I have already solved the problem for you, you should be able to write code from this. You can get a little hint with [object floatValue];