# Random number picker always picks same number only when app is first launched

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Im generating a random number string using

```
int rNumber = rand() %100000000 + 1;
_certificateReferenceField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"C/R %d", rNumber];
```

When the app is first launched or comes from being in the background it always picks the same number initially `c/R16808`?  Press it again and no problem, all works fine.

Comment: Yes, it happens. You can generate random number with a combination of date and time.

Comment: one option is to seed the rand() function, but better is to use [arc4random()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)

Comment: @Watson just wondering,  why is arc4random better, just for future reference?

Comment: @JSA986: because it seeds itself at first use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rand() is not a good random number generator, do this

```
NSInteger rNumber = arc4random() % 100000000 + 1;
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `rand`. Some will argue that `arc4random` is overkill. It depends on the needs.

Comment: You're right, depends on the case, one weak part of rand is unless you seed it every time, the sequence of numbers generated by repeatedly calling rand() will be easily predictable.

Comment: But still arc4random() gives you same value in each run.

Comment: @maddy, yes but you'd have to call this (srand()) every time, and then call rand(). Which makes it 2 lines

Comment: @AnoopVaidya that is simply not correct. arc4random() seeds itself every time you call it.

Comment: Thanks Kaann, still getting 1608 initially

Comment: I have tested in my app by writing all random numbers in a file. and after 1000 run, same answer. :(

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu No, you only call `srand` once when the app starts. Not for every call of `rand`. I just ran some tests. `arc4random` is 3 times slower than `rand`.

Comment: @maddy I get your point, of course, what I was trying to say is this:if I know the first number you produce with rand(), then I can know all the following numbers. rand() just seeds itself with the last produced number. So it's very unsafe for some applications.

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu But that's not true if `rand` is properly seeded with `srand`. Then you don't know what the first call to `rand` will return. So it is perfectly safe. But again, it depends on the need. `arc4random` is a much better choice for dealing with security and cryptography. If you simply want to put a view in a random spot on the screen, for example, `rand` is perfect and far more efficient than `arc4random`.

Comment: @maddy Once your first call returns (let's say) 32, I know that the sequence will go 32-537824-449273380-385194808-etc... Your answer is more justified in a general use case, I just sleep better at night with arc4random() :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed the random number generator using `srand`. A common use is:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Call this before any call to `rand`.

Comment: tnaks Maddy but srand(time(NULL));
    int rNumber = rand() %100000000 + 1;
    _certificateReferenceField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"C/R %d", rNumber]; still give sme 1608 for some reason initially

Comment: why not `srandomdev(void);`?

Comment: @JSA986 When I use `srand` on app startup, each call to `rand` gives me a different number each time the app is run.

Comment: I'd put the call to `srand` in `main` or your app delegate's `init` method.

Comment: Maddy Ive got it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` if thats correct?  So am i right in thinking that always sets the initial string to zero before randomising it with `srand(time(NULL));`

Comment: That's a good place too. Calling `srand` does nothing to a string. It just ensures that calls to `rand` give you a different sequence of values each time the app is run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
srandom(time(NULL));
```

to randomize your random number generation.

and then use `random()` to generate random numbers.

Comment: `srandom` is for seeding `random`, not `rand`.