# Random image generator by ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created code, so: when the view did load, show up a random image.
I've written some code, but it always starts with the same image (and viewbgcolor)..

my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(([index intValue] + 1) % 6)];
    switch ([index intValue]) {
        case 0:
            moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"angry.png"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 1:
            moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Disappointed.png"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
            break;

        case 2:
            moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glad.png"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            break;
        case 3:
            moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"happy.png"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            break;

        case 4:
            moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sad.png"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            break;

        case 5:
            moodImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"surprised.png"];
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
    }
}
```

This is really frustrating..
It works well with an IBAction, but not with the viewdidload...
Has someone a alternative block of code to let this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(([index intValue] + 1) % 6)];
```

There is no random value in this line of code.

Try this:

```
index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random_uniform(5)];
```

See "[Generating Random Numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)" for info about random numbers in objective-c

Comment: Our even better, skip the NSNumber altogether and make index an int.  +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:(([index intValue] + 1) % 6)]
```

Use

```
 arc4random(5)
```

You need to form random value for each viewDidCall, and from your code it doesn't happen.

Documentation for [arc4random()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)