# Animating UIButtons around their center very slowly

Tags: iphone

I have a UIViewController`s view on which I have a background image of cloud image. I am continuosly moving the image by keeping the imageview inside a scroll view and then scrolling the scrollview horizontally enabled with a NSTimer. This perfectly gives a picture of a moving cloud. Now , I have three UIButtons on the view . These are not in the scroll view. I want to very slowly animate these three buttons around their center randomly in such a way that they look like floating in the moving cloud. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn to move `UIView`'s on your own.  You will want to create a subclass of UIView, add subviews to it, and you can change the subview's location like so:

```
mySubview.center = CGPointMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
```

(Keep in mind the origin is in the upper lefthand corner and y increases downward)

This is the simplest way to move your `UIView`'s although you can use [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) along with the `mySubview.frame` property.

As for getting random numbers, use [arc4random()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c).

Almost everything you see in an app is a subclass of `UIView`, and that includes `UIButton`, `UIScrollView`, and `UIImageView`.  You should be able to achieve the desired effect from here.  I would also recommend you rewrite your moving clouds to use a custom subview rather than hijacking a `UIScrollView`.