# Generate Random Numbers with Fixed Digits Length?

Tags: objective-c, arc4random

I am generating Random Number with

```
int randomID = arc4random() % 3000;
```

But I want to generate random number with atleast 4 digits. like 1000, 2400, 1122

I want to know the code for Objective C.

Comment: How many time you want to generate 4 digit number ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary I want to send it messages to server it will not kept in cache it will be clean.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times. Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c/7082580#7082580. You better use a solution with `arc4random_uniform` as your upper bound is 9999 or 2999.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please try

generate numbers :1000~9999

```
int randomID = arc4random() % 9000 + 1000;
```

generate numbers :1000~2999

```
int randomID = arc4random() % 2000 + 1000;
```

Comment: Suppose if random number is 3000 and add 1000 then it will be 4000. So user wanna less then 3000. So it may be problem in future.

Comment: if it wants less than 3000 and 4 digits then you can use int randomID = arc4random() % 2000 + 1000;

Answer (score 8):

**At least** four digits, right?

So you need something with flexibility:

```
-(NSString *)getRandomPINString:(NSInteger)length
{
    NSMutableString *returnString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

    NSString *numbers = @"0123456789";

    // First number cannot be 0
    [returnString appendFormat:@"%C", [numbers characterAtIndex:(arc4random() % ([numbers length]-1))+1]];

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        [returnString appendFormat:@"%C", [numbers characterAtIndex:arc4random() % [numbers length]]];
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

**and use it like so:**

```
NSString *newPINString = [self getRandomPINString:4];
```