# How can I generate 4 - digits random number in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate a 4 digits number using C. I think that we are able to use the 'rand' function, however it generates random numbers with random digits, not only 4. We have to generate a 4 - digits number.

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this for 4digit only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051860/generate-random-numbers-with-fixed-digits-length

Answer (score 3):

you can use this if it's "randomness" isn't important:

```
1000+(rand()%9000)
```

Comment: I like it. You generate a number between 0 and 8999 and then you add 1000, moving the number to be between 1000 and 9999

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one, i hope it will help you.
**arc4random** uses a better pseudo random number generator than **random**: it generates a statistically more uniform, less predictable distribution; is based on a larger range of possible numbers.
Also, **ar4random** doesn't need to be initialized as its seed is auto-generated.

E.g. generate numbers :1000~9999

```
int randomID = arc4random() % 9000 + 1000;
```

generate numbers :1000~2999

```
int randomID = arc4random() % 2000 + 1000;
```

Comment: C does not define the PRNG to be used with `rand()` so the comparison may not be true.  OTOH, many `rand()` are weak.