# Using arc4random function to produce unique values

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random

I am creating a quiz app for the iPhone. Currently my questions are being selected randomly with the `arc4random` function.

The problem is that I want each question to be displayed only once. Is there a way that I make the `arc4random` function generate unique numbers and then stop once it has generated all possible numbers?

This is what i am currently using to generate my random number:

```
QuestionSelected = arc4random() %4;
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: One solution:
Create an array of k elements (with the id of your questions).
Then: int index = arc4Randcom()%[theArray count];
You'll get the question with [theArray objectAtIndex:index].
Then, remove the question: [theArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "random permutation" or "random shuffle".

Comment: Y used Larme approach some time ago

Comment: Use the method mentioned by @Larme and `arc4random_uniform([theArray count])`.  The reasons for `arc4random_uniform` can be found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Comment: Was my answer useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *questions=[NSMutableArray new];
//creating an array to save questions
// Place in viewDidLoad
for(;;) {
    //randomly select question
    QuestionSelected = arc4random() % 4;
    //check if question contains this number
    //if it does - continue looping
    if(![questions containsObject:@(QuestionSelected)]){
        //so it doesn't - we add this number to array
        [questions addObject:@(QuestionSelected)];
        break;
        //and exit loop
    }

 }
```

Thats all

Comment: You fancy explaining your code????

Comment: Depending on how many question there are this could slow down randomly trying to find a number thats not used

Comment: I tried this but I was getting error "implicit conversion of 'int' to 'Id' is disallowed with ARC

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `NSMutableArray` with the questions, and when a question is selected, remove it from the array. In this case you would generate the random number between 0 and `array.count - 1`