# Random Image Generator not working

Tags: image, random, switch-statement, case, generator

I have a game that produces 1 of 6 random images when btnStart is pressed.  I am using int randomImages followed by a switch statement with cases 0 - 5.   However, case 1 is the only image that shows up every time.  Case 0 and cases 2-5 do not show up.  No matter what order I set the images, it is only case 1 that is shown.
Are there any alternatives to switch cases when using a random image generator?

```
int randomImages = rand() % 6;
switch (randomImages) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed the `rand()` function or you'll get the same result every time. Try using `int randomImages = arc4random_uniform(6);` instead.

Also see: [Generating random numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c)