# Randomly shuffling a number sequence

Tags: iphone, objective-c, random, numbers, shuffle

I need help in randomly arranging number sequence in Obj-C for example,
1-4, it'll be 3,1,2,4 or 1,4,3,2. I know it involves this function `arc4random()`.
Any suggestions/tips?

Comment: You may find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791232/canonical-way-to-randomize-an-nsarray-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a Shuffling Category for `NSMutableArray`:

[What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray/56656#56656)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `int iRandomNum = arc4random() % 4`, and use the output accordingly in for loop