# Shuffling an array in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

I develop apps for iphone/iPad.I want to shuffle the objects stored in an NSArray.Is there any way to achieve it with objective-c?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a category to NSMutableArray, with [code provided by Kristopher Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray/56656#56656) -

```
//  NSMutableArray_Shuffling.h

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif

// This category enhances NSMutableArray by providing
// methods to randomly shuffle the elements.
@interface NSMutableArray (Shuffling)
- (void)shuffle;
@end


//  NSMutableArray_Shuffling.m

#import "NSMutableArray_Shuffling.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffling)

- (void)shuffle
{

  static BOOL seeded = NO;
  if(!seeded)
  {
    seeded = YES;
    srandom(time(NULL));
  }

    NSUInteger count = [self count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: It is repeating array elements

Comment: It's not good practice to copy someone else's answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray>

Comment: Note that the original answer has been improved, so use it rather than this old copy of the original. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray/56656#56656

Answer (score 2):

See if this [sample](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/shuffling-arrays.html) helps.

You can see this previous SO question too [canonical way to randomize an NSArray in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791232/canonical-way-to-randomize-an-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thank you,a voteup for this info.