# set UIButton's Image by array of Images randomly

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios4, uibutton, uiimage

I need your help as I dont know how can I set the background image of my UIButtons from array of images. I have 10 UIButtons and an array of 10 images. I want to set the images from array randomly. Please tel me how this can be possible.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659718/shuffling-an-array-in-objective-c) is an answer that is worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

This may need tweaking a bit, I haven't tested it, but the concept should be ok.

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png", @"2.png", ...., nil];

int index = arc4random() % 10;
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[arr objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

1)First declare a NSMutableArray in which you will store the images :

```
NSMutableArray *yourImgArray;
```

2)Allocate the array in .m file :

`yourImgArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",nil`];

3)Set the images while setting the tags(in your loop):

```
[yourButtonInstance setBackgroundImage:yourImageInstance forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope it helps !!