# Force Shuffle NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a NSMutableArray called putNumberUsed. It contains the following objects @"blah1,@"blah2",@"blah3",@"blah4". I want to shuffle these objects randomly so for example if I chose:

```
 [putNumberUsed objectAtIndex:0]
```

**it would give me anything but "blah1"**. How would I go about doing this? The following is the code I used thus far:

```
NSMutableArray *putNumbersUsed = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:@"blah1",@"blah2",@"blah3",@"blah4",nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659718/shuffling-an-array-in-objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, You can write a loop for that. Please check the following code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < putNumberUsed.count; i++) {
    int randomInt1 = arc4random() % [putNumberUsed count];
    int randomInt2 = arc4random() % [putNumberUsed count];
    [putNumberUsed exchangeObjectAtIndex:randomInt1 withObjectAtIndex:randomInt2];
}
```

I this this may be useful to you.

Comment: Not very good algorithm. Use only one random index and exchange object at this index with object at `i`.

Comment: Yes, you are right onegray, we can use only one random value.

Comment: Also, don't use % on a random value, it messes up the distribution. Use arc4random_uniform() instead.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shuffling solution with all positions forced to change when count > 1.

Add a category like NSMutableArray+Shuffle.m:

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffle)
// Fisher-Yates shuffle variation with all positions forced to change
- (void)unstableShuffle
{
    for (NSInteger i = self.count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        // note: we use u_int32_t because `arc4random_uniform` doesn't support int64
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)i)];
}
@end
```

Then you can shuffle like:

```
[putNumbersUsed unstableShuffle];
```

This solution:

- has no [modulo bias](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx)
- has no [naive bias](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/)
- has no [sorting bias](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html)

A Swift 3.2 and Swift 4 equivalent is:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func unstableShuffle() {
        for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: 0, by: -1) {
            swapAt(i, Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i))))
        }
    }
}
```

A Swift 3.0 and 3.1 equivalent is:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func unstableShuffle() {
        for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: 0, by: -1) {
            swap(&self[i], &self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i)))])
        }
    }
}
```

Note: [An algorithm for regular shuffling (where a result with same positions being possible) is also available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33840745/1033581)

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 10.x++ new [concept of shuffle array](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1640855-shuffled) is given by Apple,

You need to import the framework :

**ObjeC**

```
#import <GameplayKit/GameplayKit.h>

NSArray *shuffledArray = [yourArray shuffledArray];
```

**Swift**

```
import GameplayKit

let shuffledArray = yourArray.shuffled()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: those methods may return an unmodified array, which is not what is being asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can shuffle the object by using the following line of code,

```
[putNumbersUsed exchangeObjectAtIndex:3 withObjectAtIndex:0];
```

I think this may useful to you.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh I was looking for something like this but isn't this only exchanging object at 3 with 0? What if I wanted to do this randomly with all. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I think Rajesh wanted to guide you to the right direction. I posted a very similiar code in my answer, so have a look.

Answer (score 1):

generate a random number for index

```
int randomInt = arc4random() % [putNumberUsed count];
[putNumberUsed objectAtIndex:randomInt];
```

Comment: what if the same index was generated several times ? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [putNumberUsed count]; i++) {
    int random = arc4random() % [putNumberUsed count]; 
    [putNumbersUsed exchangeObjectAtIndex:random withObjectAtIndex:i]; 
}
```

Comment: you must recalculate random in each iteration!!