# Random number generator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a quiz application. I want to generate a random question. The questions come from Core Data. When view didAppear is called I store the question in an array and display it by a display question method. But i want to display the questions randomly without repeating any question, and every question will display. How can I do this ?

Comment: Just trying to get a feel for your post here...How are the questions stored in Core Data? Is there a way you can easily say "I want question X"?

Comment: I would create a random sequence of `0..n-1` (it represents the indices of the `n` questions), and I would read the questions by that order of the indices from the database sequentially; and you won't run into a situation when a question is shown twice as every index exists only once; that looks the most straightforward solution to me; it can be achieved in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy your questions in an tmp array and each time a question is randomly picked by a random function (eg : `int r = arc4random() % [myArray count];`) you delete its entrance from the tmp array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shuffle the array.  Look here:

[canonical way to randomize an NSArray in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791232/canonical-way-to-randomize-an-nsarray-in-objective-c)