# What's the shortest bit of code that returns keys/elements from a dictionary in random order?

Tags: ios, sorting

I'm looking to access the keys/elements from a dictionary in random, non-repeating, order. What's the shortest bit of ios code to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have NSMutableArray's -shuffle category from [canonical way to randomize an NSArray in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791232/canonical-way-to-randomize-an-nsarray-in-objective-c).

```
NSMutableArray *suffledKeys = [[dict allKeys] mutableCopy];
[suffledKeys shuffle];
for (id randomKey in shuffledKeys) {
    id randomValue = [dict objectForKey:randomKey];
    // What ever you need to do.
}
```

Hope this helps.