# Objective C - Call Array objects in a random order

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a populated NSArray. I want to be able to print out the contents of the Array in a random order so that each Object is only printed out once. The next time I print them out I want them to be in an entirely different order to what they were printed out as before. If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Lollipop

Comment: Make a mutable copy, shuffle, print, repeat.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791232/canonical-way-to-randomize-an-nsarray-in-objective-c

Comment: What the heck is going on? It feels like this questions pops up twice a day ...