# how to programmatically change the components in a picker

Tags: uipicker

I have a picker with 5 components and each component holds the same NSArray filled with @"1" up to @"5". My question is how do i go about being able to change the contents of the picker after the user enters in any number to seed a random generator so that the components of each picker are "jumbled up" in relation to each other (this being after the initial viewDidLoad implementation where each component is identical ie. dip lays 1-5)

as an example this is what an ideal result would look like.

1 5 2 4 2

2 4 4 1 5

5 2 3 1 3

4 3 1 4 2

1 4 2 5 3

as a learner of obj-c i am just looking for guidance to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for any comments that may be made.

Comment: Probably related: [canonical way to randomize an NSArray in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791232/canonical-way-to-randomize-an-nsarray-in-objective-c)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch that wasn't quite what i was looking for although it does prove useful to me as i might try another approach. Thanks