# How to sort randomly with CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, core-data

I am using NSFetchRequest to fetch some items, which could be sorted by Popular, or Random.

Following the guides, I could sort the items by popularity easily using NSSortDescriptor.

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"popularity" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

But how do I sort them randomly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there such a thing as a "random sort"?

If you want to randomly permute the display of results obtained via `NSFetchedResultsController`, remember that you are populating your table view based on an `indexPath` reference to an element in your controller's fetched results (`-objectAtIndexPath:`).

So one thing you can do is shuffle an `NSMutableArray` (or arrays) of index paths, writing a method that maps an index path to a permuted index path. This method takes an index path as input, looks up the array (or arrays) and spits out a new index path as output. You use this new index path to populate your table view.

Alternatively, you can add a `randomizerTag` attribute to your `Item` entity. You use any permutation function to generate a permutation of integers `{ 1 ... n }` and save those numbers to each record in your store. Once saved, you can refetch, applying a sort descriptor that sorts on the `randomizerTag` values of your records.

Comment: Haha "random sort" sounds contradictory. But yea, what i want is really a sort that is random.

Suggestion 1 sounds like a way to do. But I did encounter weird behaviour from tableview when mapping index path to the fetchedResults. I'll try anyway.

Suggestion 2 is a hackaround. I would try not to touch my entity properties. But if all else fail, I'll try this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to create your objects with a randomized property then sort by that.

Comment: Any guide on how to create randomized property?

This is not creating an int property with random numbers, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch your objects, put them in an `NSMutableArray`, and shuffle it, as discussed here:

[What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray)

Comment: I am using NSFetchedResultsController for iPhone's table, so i don't think i should get fetchedObjects and sort it