# how to get select elements randomly from an array

Tags: iphone

i have an array with 12 objects {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}

from this array i have to pick 6 values randomly,but they are unique not repeated.

i am using this

```
for (int i =0; i<6; i++) 
{
    NSLog(@"%d",rand()%12);

}
```

it gets as 7 1 5 2 10 8

for second time it gets as 0 2 11 1 0 5,Here 0 is repeated.But i always need as my first output means values are not repeated.

how can i done,

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: This question can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray  Then you pick up your 6 values from the array ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1) Make a list of unique elements from the original list

2) Use the rand procedure that you mentioned to pick elements from the new list.

To solve 1), I think there are 2 ways

1a) Sort the elements. With the sorted array it should be easy to filter out the duplicate elements.

1b) Create a object of the NSSet class to create a set of elements. Go through the array and add the elements to the NSSet object. NSSet will have unique elements from the original array.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a mutable copy of the array and each time removing the element from the copy of the array and reducing the array length you use by one?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Get the random number using rand().
2. Check if the previous no is the same if yes get random number again. Else add the generated no to the result array.
3. Repeat till u get the required number of elements in ur result array

Hope this helps..

Comment: i think it is a long process,if i have 40 images need to select 20 images,then i need to retrieve 20 times and check it 20 times if same then the process is extends

Answer (score 0):

use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm to shuffle your array. 
than take first 6 elements.

Comment: Fisher-Yates won't filter out multiple elements that are the same. The first 6 elements could all be the same after you do the shuffle.

Comment: if array is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11} using shuffling you will never get something like {1,2,1,3,4,3}. i think that's what op want.

Comment: Yes. That is true. I had thought that the array could be any sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Mahesh: The link provided by  j_freyre directly answers your question, and also gives usable source code :)