# Generate random strings using NSArray in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, string, random, nsarray

I have one array and it has some data. Now i want to randomly changed the positions of the strings which means, want to shuffle the strings into the array. But i don't want to change the order of the array, I want to changed only order the strings and doesn't changed the array index position.

My actual array is (

```
         (
        first,
        second,
        third,
        fourth
    ),
        (
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four
    ),
        (
        sample,
        test,
        demo,
        data
    )
)
```

Expected result,

```
  (
        (
        second,
        fourth,
        third,
        first
    ),
        (
         Two,
         Four,
         One,
         Three
    ),
        (
        test,
        demo,
        sample,
        data
    )
)
```

Please Help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`NSIndexSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is designed for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to do. You should do the following:

Add a category to NSArray. The following implementation is from [Kristopher Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175/kristopher-johnson) as he replied in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray) question.

```
// This category enhances NSMutableArray by providing
// methods to randomly shuffle the elements.
@interface NSMutableArray (Shuffling)
- (void)shuffle;
@end


//  NSMutableArray_Shuffling.m

#import "NSMutableArray_Shuffling.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (Shuffling)

- (void)shuffle
{


    NSUInteger count = [self count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
}

@end
```

Now you have a method called shuffle, which shuffels your array. Now you can do the following so that only the strings in the inner arrays are shuffled:

```
for (NSMutableArray *array in outerArray) {
   [array shuffle];
}
```

Now the inner Arrays are shuffled. 
But keep in mind, that the inner arrays need to be NSMutableArrays. Else you won't be able to shuffle them. ;-)

Sandro Meier

Answer (score 0):

int randomIndex;

```
for( int index = 0; index < [array count]; index++ )
{
    randomIndex= rand() % [array count] ;

    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:index withObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
}
[array retain];
```