# how to make "Farm Flip - Memory Match for Kids" like memory based game

Tags: iphone

i'm about to developp a memory game for children [like](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/farm-flip-memory-match-for/id380346867?mt=8),i have 6 different images show in in random order in 12 places. note(each image show twice) and i want to know how to set images randomly and how to mach  UIImage with animation? any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the answer by Kristopher at [What's the Best Way to Shuffle an NSMutableArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-an-nsmutablearray). You can create an array of 12 images (each repeated twice) & then shuffle the array. Then display the images in the order obtained after shuffling.

Regarding animations, you first need to at least *visualize* what animation you want. People can then help you achieve that.

HTH,

Akshay